# Not setting arguments properly in rails tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I am curious as to why my `args` variable is always coming back as `{}` in the following task:

```
desc "Create an Api Key assuming one doesn't exist."
task :create_api_key, [:name] => :environment do | t, args |
  if !ApiKey.find_by_application_name(args[:name])
    binding.pry
    if ApiKey.new(:application_name => args[:name], :api_key => SecureRandom.hex(32)).save!
      puts "Your key is: " + ApiKey.find_by_application_name(args[:name]).api_key
    else
      puts "Could not create the api key, you might be missing an argument: Application Name."
    end
  else
    puts "This application already contains an api key."
  end
end
```

The following is a run of the task (**Note the `binding.pry`**):

```
$ bin/rake create_api_key "xaaron_test"

From: /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/BlackBird/lib/tasks/create_api_key.rake @ line 4 :

    1: desc "Create an Api Key assuming one doesn't exist."
    2: task :create_api_key, [:name] => :environment do | t, args |
    3:   if !ApiKey.find_by_application_name(args[:name])
 => 4:     binding.pry
    5:     if ApiKey.new(:application_name => args[:name], :api_key => SecureRandom.hex(32)).save!
    6:       puts "Your key is: " + ApiKey.find_by_application_name(args[:name]).api_key
    7:     else
    8:       puts "Could not create the api key, you might be missing an argument: Application Name."
    9:     end

[1] pry(main)> args
=> {}
```

Even if I do `bin/rake create_api_key xaaron_test` I get the same issue. What is going on? is there some small mistake some where I forgot about?

## Update

I also spit out `t` to see what was in there:

```
pry(main)> t
=> <Rake::Task create_api_key => [environment]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass arguments to a task by enclosing them in [] directly after the task name.

e.g.

```
rake create_api_key[xaaron_test]
```

If you use zsh, you need to escape the opening [

e.g.

```
rake create_api_key\[xaaron_test]
```